# sql query from two tables

Tags: sql, database

I have two tables (customers, admin) A user logs in by email and password, I need to check if either the email and password exists in the customer or admin table. The emails are unquie so won't have a problem there. This is for uni work, obviously I would have a better database design than this but I have to use what is given.
I have this:

```
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM customer, admin WHERE cus_email = '$email'
 AND cus_password = '$password' OR admin_email = '$email' AND admin_password = '$password'";
```

Am not very good with Joins so I havent attempted one on this.

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really need a UNION rather than a JOIN here:

```
SELECT username
  FROM Customer
 WHERE cus_email = ? AND cus_password = ?
UNION
SELECT adminname AS username
  FROM admin
 WHERE admin_email = ? AND admin_password = ?
```

You should either use placeholders - the question marks - or protect yourself against [SQL Injection](http://xkcd.com/327) attacks.  There are functions to help you do that in PHP.

Comment: Thanks, I would be using stored procedures but the tutor doesn't teach that so apparently I cannot use them.

Comment: @Elliott: Even inside a stored procedure, if you build the SQL dynamically (as a string) you have to be careful.  If you use placeholders in some form, you should be safe.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT cus_id as id, 'false' as IsAdmin 
FROM customer
WHERE cus_email = '$email' 
    AND cus_password = '$password' 
UNION ALL    
SELECT admin_id as id, 'true' as IsAdmin
FROM admin
WHERE admin_email = '$email' 
    AND admin_password = '$password'";
```